# How to bold first line of paragraph till comma in word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

if i have a paragraph for example

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

What in need to do is to bold first line of paragraph till comma

**The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog,** The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

for all paragraphs in Word using VBA.

Comment: Welcome!  Perhaps you misunderstand how this site works.  Please see "[mcve]" as well as "[ask]" and add some more information to your question.  More great [tips here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: As you've seen, you're expected to have shown some effort when posting on Stack Overflow. Try recording a macros: when you use a wildcard search to find: paragraph mark, any text, followed by a comma. You'll find lots of explanation how to use wildcards in Word's Find if you Google. When you have the code, even if it isn't exactly what you want, but almost, use the [edit] link to copy/paste the code into your question. Then we can help you polish it to be what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Test()
Dim p As Paragraph
Dim idx As Integer
Dim i As Integer
For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

With p.Range
    idx = InStr(1, .Text, ",", vbTextCompare)
    If idx > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To idx
            .Characters(i).Bold = True
        Next i
    End If
End With

Next p
End Sub
```

Loops over each paragraph, finds the first Comma, bolds all characters including the first comma.

Input:
Sample paragraph, some text.

Output:
**Sample paragraph,** some text.

It isn't the most optimal code, since it loops over the characters, but it's tested and works and should give the idea for what you're after. Skips paragraphs without comma's.